# Sending "Cache-Control : no-cache" from cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cache-control

I have a file, stored on S3, let's say index.html which is changing once in a while.

I don't want end customer to cache it, so I want to send a http header `max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate`.

From what I understand from the doc, if I set this header in S3 metadata, Cloudfront will respect this header, which means Cloudfront will always reread the file for each request.

I don't want Cloudfront to do that, I am happy to invalidate Cloudfront whenever the file has changed.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *if I set this header in S3 metadata, Cloudfront will respect this header, which means Cloudfront will always reread the file for each request.*

That isn't correct.

When `Minimum TTL` in CloudFront is set larger than `max-age` or `s-maxage`, or when the origin response includes any of the `no-cache`, `no-store`, and/or `private` directives, CloudFront still stores the objects for up to the Minimum TTL.

This is why it is called the "minimum" TTL.  CloudFront assumes objects with a TTL shorter than this (as indicated by those directives) should still be cached -- just not longer than Minimum TTL.  So if this is a large value, the number of requests to S3 will be minimal.

See [Specifying How Long Objects Stay in a CloudFront Edge Cache (Expiration)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html).